# Select distinct and get sum of timestamp differences

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select, distinct

I don't know if this is possible, but it'd be really awesome. I have a table of sign-ins for people who are logging time on different projects and I need to compile a report of time logged for each project for a given time period.

My table looks something like this:

```
id | project | time_in             | time_out            | break
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1       | 2014-12-07 05:00:00 | 2014-12-07 10:00:00 | 30
2  | 2       | 2014-12-07 06:00:00 | 2014-12-07 13:00:00 | 15
3  | 1       | 2014-12-07 14:00:00 | 2014-12-07 18:00:00 | 0
4  | 3       | 2014-12-07 08:30:00 | 2014-12-07 18:45:00 | 75
5  | 2       | 2014-12-07 12:00:00 | 2014-12-07 16:30:00 | 0
```

What I'd like to be able to do is get a report of the time logged for each project given a date range, i.e. the total time, probably in seconds, logged for each project.

`time_in` and `time_out` are fields of type `TIMESTAMP`; `break` is an integer representing the number of *minutes* the person was on break. I need to get the sum of `time_out - time_in - break` for each project, e.g. for December 7:

```
project | time
---------------
1       | 34200
2       | 40500
3       | 34200
```

This is all I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `project`
FROM `sign_ins`
WHERE
    `time_in` >= '2014-12-07 00:00:00' AND
    `time_out` <= '2014-12-08 00:00:00';
```

I appreciate your help on this, SO community. You guys are so brilliant.

Comment: One issue I see is that you don't distinguish during what minutes the person took a break. If there are situations where the time_in is before 12/7, and the time_out is on or after 12/7, and they took a break, you don't know what portion of the break falls in 12/7.

Comment: Yes, that is a potential limitation in the schema. The interface, however, restricts time out to be the same date as time in (or midnight the following day), i.e. if you work 6pm to 6am, you need to log two entries: 6pm-12am on the first day, 12am-6am the second, entering break times separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the difference in seconds by converting the date/time values to Unix time stamps.  Then, just aggregate the differences using `sum()`:

```
SELECT project,
       SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_out) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_in) - (break * 60)) as DiffSecs
FROM `sign_ins`
WHERE `time_in` >= '2014-12-07 00:00:00' AND
      `time_out` <= '2014-12-08 00:00:00'
GROUP BY project;
```

Comment: you left out the break part :)

Comment: I can just do `SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_out) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_in) - break * 60)`, right?

Comment: @MMiller no you need parenthesis around the break*60 see the edit I did on his answer

Comment: Thanks much for your help, guys. I shouldn't need the parentheses, right? Wouldn't order of operations imply that multiplication gets evaluated first, or does SQL always evaluate left-to-right?

Comment: @MMiller I would keep it in there just incase it tries to multiply more than just break. and Gordon you're welcome :) I learn something new / a better way to do it almost every time you answer :)